# Entering values to a dialogbox from windows scripting languages like vbs or WSh

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I have a web page which when opened gives a dialog box for entering the user name and password. I am tired of giving the username & password every time. Can I code it into a windows script so that when I run the script, it will navigate to that page in IE and will fill the username textbox and password textbox in the dialogbox and click the OK button?

I have tried the following script in VBScript for navigating. the IE opens and navigates to the location but I'm stuck when the dialog box opens prompting for a username and password.
How do I fill them automatically from code?

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
IE.Navigate "http://www.google.co.in" 
IE.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods of accomplishing this.

1. `SendKeys` - You can use the SendKeys method to insert the username and password.  It works, but it's not bulletproof and relies heavily upon the app behaving exactly as you anticipate.
2. HTTP Headers - You can set the HTTP headers so that they provide the username and password when requesting the page.  IMHO, this is overly complicated.
3. Change the URL - If your page is using basic authentication, you can provide the username or username/password combination as a part of the page url.  It looks like this:
   `http://username:password@www.mysite.com`

Using this method, you don't even need a script.  You can save a bookmark or shortcut with the URL.  Understand, of course, the security risk of storing a password in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are asking about Basic Authentication dialog.

See my answer here:

[Equivalent of DefaultCredentials in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709648/equivalent-of-defaultcredentials-in-vbscript/9891107#9891107)